# Efficiently generating all sequences by selecting word from position specific word pool at each position

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

I have a certain sequence like;

```
x y a
x could represent two words "Xerox" and "Copy".
y could represent three words "china", "DRC" and "Chinese".
a could represent two words "jinx" and "omen"
```

The sequence could be at max consisting of 6 words. I have a map from each item in sequence to it's equivalent strings in vector container. So the main objective is to get all the possible word combinations by using different options available for each item. For example, for the above case, all possible outputs are ...

```
Xerox china jinx
Xerox china omen
Xerox DRC jinx
Xerox DRC omen
Xerox Chinese jinx
Xerox Chinese omen
Copy china jinx
Copy china omen
Copy DRC jinx
Copy DRC omen
Copy Chinese jinx
Copy Chinese omen
```

Currently I am thinking of recursive implementation, but i am unable to project the idea clearly in my solution. I would appreciate your suggestions and ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need any recursion.

The can enumerate all the possibilities like this:

- the index of x can be zero or one.
- the index of y can be zero, one or two.
- the index of a can be zero or one.

More generally you just want to count while incrementing the next bin on overflow and terminating your loop when the last bin overflows.  Imagine if you only had two choices each you would simply have a binary counter, you'd keep incrementing it, and each bit in that counter would select either the first or second words.  This is no different.

The algorithm would look something like this:

```
Initialize num_lists to number of word lists.
Initialize word lists per position.
Initialize max_count array for the number of words per position.
Initialize count array to all zeros.
Repeat
  Print words corresponding to count array (count_array[0] select first word etc.)
  Carry = 1 // We're basically adding 1 to our counter
  Index = 0
  While Carry and Index<num_lists
    Add Carry to count[Index]
    If count[Index]==max_count[Index] then Carry=1; max_count[Index] = 0
    Else Carry = 0
    Index = Index + 1
  End
While Carry==0
```

Comment: well, could you be more elaborate? I am sorry but i couldn't get your idea clearly(i am still trying to think about your idea).

Comment: @consumer There you go.  Think about it as performing an addition algorithm but where every digit can have a different range and where each digit corresponds to a choice of a word.

Comment: I will look into your suggestion. And if this works flawlessly, i will definitely accept your answer. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @consumer: Before thinking about the code think about the problem.  look at your question, the first position goes, "jinx", "omen", "jinx", "omen"... 0, 1, 0, 1... The next position goes, "china", "china", "DRC", "DRC"... so we have 000, 001, 010, 011, 020, 021, 100, 101... we're counting, right?

Comment: I was able to implement with different implementation. But the basic idea was to use Nary counting restricted by the pool size in every position. I am accepting your answer because of the IDEA. Thank you.

Comment: @consumer: np.  what's wrong with the pseudo code?  let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: The inner while loop never advances properly in your algorithm.

Comment: @consumer: Hmm. Looks OK to me... Perhaps you put the Index+=1 inside the else clause?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44111/discussion-between-consumer-and-guy-sirton)

Answer (score 0):

I think a recursive solution is a good way to go if you want your code to be readable. If you can have too many dimensions you obviously risk a stack overflow, but otherwise I'd personally prefer recursion.

The code below assumes you have a bi-dimensional array of strings, represented as a `vector < vector<string> >` which I called `v`.

The key is to keep track of the index in each dimension. I use an array of ints to do that. Given that I know which string I want from each set of strings, it's easy to print them out:

```
void printSequence(const vector< vector<string> > &v, const vector<int> &indices) {
    int n = indices.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << v[i][indices[i]];
        if (i < n - 1) {
            cout << " ";
        } else {
          cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

A recursive call is a simple way of constructing one such array. `d` here stands for dimension. At each recursive level, we fill the `indices` array with one more element, inserted at `d`. When we have all of them, we can print them out.

```
void print(const vector< vector<string> > &v, vector<int> &indices, int d) {
    int n = v.size();
    if (d == n) {
        printSequence(v, indices);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v[d].size(); i++) {
        indices.push_back(i);
        print(v, indices, d + 1);
        indices.pop_back();
    }
}
```

If you think about your example, the indices array being used at the end would look like this:

- 0, 0, 0
- 0, 0, 1
- 0, 1, 0
- 0, 1, 1
- 0, 2, 0
- 0, 2, 1
- 1, 0, 0
- ...
- 1, 2, 1

Assuming you already have v populated, you can call `print` like this:

```
vector<int> indices;
print(v, indices, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print(vector<vector<string> >& var, vector<string>& to_print, int level)
{

    if(level == var.size() - 1)

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < var[level].size(); ++i)
        {
            std::copy(to_print.begin(), to_print.end(), 
                        ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ","));
            cout  << var[level][i] << endl;
        }
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < var[level].size(); ++i)
    {
        to_print.push_back(var[level][i]);
        print(var, to_print, level + 1);
        to_print.pop_back();
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    vector<vector<string> > var;
    string X[] = { "Xerorx", "Copy"};
    string Y[] = { "china", "DRC", "chinease"};
    string Z[] = { "jinx", "omen"};
    var.push_back(vector<string>(X, X + 2));
    var.push_back(vector<string>(Y, Y + 3));
    var.push_back(vector<string>(Z, Z + 2));

    vector<string> to_print;
    print(var, to_print, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just the cartesian product of the vectors, `x × (y × (a × ...))`, so it might be intuitive to code it that way.

Recursion is a good idea because the problem is recursive in nature. It's a `foldr`, which is a common functional pattern, but requires an initial value (in this case, a vector with an empty string)

```
vector<string> cartesian_concat(const vector<string>& a, 
                                const vector<string>& b) {
    vector<string> result;
    for (const string& i : a)
        for (const string& j : b)
            result.push_back(i + " " + j);
    return result;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
U vec_foldr(U (*f)(const T&, const U&), 
            const U& init, 
            const vector<T>& l, 
            unsigned pos=0) {
    if (pos < l.size())
        return f(l.at(pos), vec_foldr(f, init, l, pos+1));
    return init;
}
```

---

```
vector<vector<string>> m {
    { "Xerox", "Copy" },
    { "china", "DRC", "Chinese" },
    { "jinx", "omen" }};

for (const string& i : vec_foldr(cartesian_concat, { "" }, m))
    cout << i << endl;
```